# Does revision of Support library matter?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I was trying to add appcompat support libraries to my project. I am working with API 21 as my project sdk. I have support libraries 21, 22 and 23. None of them work out of the box.

And With a little digging, I came up with a possible explanation for why that is. I think it might be because the compat library contains usage of APIs that are not in the project sdk. E.G the revision 23 refers to SearchEvent which is not available until API 23.

That being said, What is the relationship between revision and API? Which revision can I use with which sdk?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally speaking, set your `compileSdkVersion` to match the major revision of the Android support libraries that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Target the version for **API 21**, you should use the support libraries with **version 21** on it.

For example -
if  `targetSdkVersion 22`

You should use v7 in Sync with 22
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'`.

If you use support library with version 23 on it, The support library assumes that you are running on API version 23 and will have updated SDK API. This will cause issues.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Sha

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by working with API 21?
You should always target the latest version of the SDK that is API 23 (as of today).

If you want your app to be compatible 21+ then just set minSDK to 21.

To come back to your real question, any support library should work since for example v7 is for API 7 (Android 2.1+)